# Create a manpage addressing several executables

Tags: debian, man

I am packaging an application with a bunch of executables accepting roughly the same arguments. I would like to write (and provide) only one manpage with common explanations and the list of arguments.

In short, I would like that

```
man execFoo
man execBar
```

point to the same page.

I know how to generate two identical `execFoo.1` and `execBar.1` but they seem suboptimal. Since I plan to release this package for Debian, solutions relying on Debian packaging chain (such as `dh_installmake`) would also be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not simply create one manpage and make the others links? That's how most, if not all, such programs do it. For example:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/man/man1/[ef]*grep.1.gz 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 27  2013 /usr/share/man/man1/egrep.1.gz -> grep.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 27  2013 /usr/share/man/man1/fgrep.1.gz -> grep.1.gz
```

As you can see above, `egrep` and `fgrep` are links to the main `grep` man page which is why `man egrep` brings up `man grep`.

Comment: That is in fact the recommended method. The alternative, which is mentioned as "deprecated" in some manuals, is to use a `.so` request to include the referenced manpage